# How can I add an extra text line in a legend of matlab graph?

Tags: matlab-figure

I need some help!!!!!

I have following legend in a line graph in Matlab:

```
--- Esme
--- Manta
--- Senchu
```

with their respectives lines --- , but I want to have a extra text in the top of the legend like:

```
SOURCES
--- Esme
--- Manta
--- Senchu
```

How can I add such text?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MATLAB version prior to 2014b, you can use the method detailed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/29137#answer_37478):

```
hLeg = legend('Esme','Manta','Senchu'); %// Create the legend and get a handle to it.
hTitle = get(hLeg,'Title');             %// Get a handle to the legend's Title.
set(hTitle,'String','SOURCES');         %// Set the desired title.
```

For newer versions of MATLAB (or handle graphics, to be precise) the above is no longer an option (as mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159515#answer_156061)), in which case you can use [this File Exchange submission](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48331-add-a-title-to-a-legend) to get the desired result. This method works by obtaining the `Position` of the legend, creating an `axes` at the same coordinates and then set *its* `Title` to something.

Please also refer to [this UndocumentedMatlab post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-legend-title) which discusses your exact question.